# C# stop watch showing random times

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I am trying to calculate time taken to run a block of code. When I run the application it shows random times for every time I execute. What may be the issue here?

```
var myTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Boss !");
}

myTimer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Try a bigger sample size.

Comment: When you say "random" times, you really mean "times that are not all the same value", right? Most likely it would have to do with what else is going on in your environment. And that a *really* small loop to be measuring.

Comment: you mean this considers even environment time apart from code execution time.

Comment: Yes, and there's also "warm up" time for the first iteration. When I run your code in a loop 30 times, the first time took `3804` milliseconds, the rest of the times were between `145` and `169` milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1.- There is no issue in your code but I'd use it like:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
//// YOUR LOOP OR CODE GOES HERE
stopwatch.Stop();
elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine($"YOUR LOOP OR CODE took {elapsedTime} ms");
```

And if you want to reuse the stopwatch you must reset it doing:

```
 stopwatch.Reset();
```

Just before starting again.

2nd.- Execution time (with every software on your computer, not only this code) depends on your machine workload, consider that resources (processor and disk) are shared, IS the OS who determines processes priority and thread management and that sort of stuff, so, you won't get same values for different executions.

Answer (score -1):

Execution of for loop iteration highly depends upon a Machine resources.
Execution times will vary time to time, based upon the resource availability.

If you are concerned about testing Stop watch then try the below code :)
Of course, most of the time you will get a constant result.

```
            var myTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            myTimer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Actually, even then you get inconsistent results. I ran that in a loop 30 times (using 1000 for the sleep), and the results were between: 1000 and 1009 milliseconds!

Comment: Yes, Agree. Because the thread can sleep for 1000ms and won't start immediately, so it will be 1000ms + microseconds